# How to get date created from OneDrive File Item

Tags: c#, uwp

I am able to get the drive item using this code below but am unable to get the drive item date created.

```
var onedrive = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(new[] { "wl.signin", "onedrive.appfolder" });
await onedrive.AuthenticateAsync();
var item = onedrive.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath("Backups/ei-backup.xml");

if (item != null)
   {
      // Get date created here?
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the Microsoft.OneDriveSDK loaded in my NuGet Package Manager, however it was version 1.2. which is missing a Microsoft Graph module. I updated it to 2.0.7 and also had to add Microsoft.OneDriveSDK.Authentication (1.0.10). Then I had to register my app with: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade

At the same portal, I had to add the permissions needed for reading.

Then I was able to implement Richard Zhang's suggestion. And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this document](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/docs/items.md) to get the `Item` according to the file path.

```cs
var item = await oneDriveClient
                     .Drive
                     .Special
                     .AppRoot
                     .ItemWithPath("path/to/file/txt")
                     .Request()
                     .GetAsync();
```

Then you can get the file creation date by `Item.CreatedDateTime`.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying I have to use Microsoft Graph?

Comment: Hi, the subsequent updates of the OneDrive api will be based on `Microsoft Graph`, so `Microsoft Graph` is the recommended choice.

Comment: That sure is a lot of overhead just to get info on a file Item that I already have access to. I will have to add the bloat code and test it out before I mark this as closed.

Comment: Hi, are you currently using the `OneDrive-Sdk-csharp` from the link I gave? If you think its overhead is acceptable, you can continue to use it, and use it to obtain the file creation date as shown in my answer.